# How to call a method on button click on custom button

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uibutton

I have CustomCell I want that when I click a button which is in CustomCell that it should alert. So how to access the method of that CustomCell

```
  @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

IBOutlet UIImageView    *imageViewCell;
IBOutlet UILabel        *theTitle;
IBOutlet UIButton*imageButton;


  }

  @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton*imageButton;
  @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageViewCell;
  @property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *theTitle;

 -(IBAction)imageButtonAction;

 @end



     @implementation CustomCell

     @synthesize imageViewCell;
     @synthesize theTitle;

    -(IBAction)imageButtonAction{


     }
```

Instead of calling this method here I want that this method should envoke in the class where I am using CustomCell any idea how to do this.

Comment: [CustomCell. imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonImageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: as par @Manohar says you can get Button click Event and if you want get different Even For each Cell button you can give Tag like `CustomCell. imageButton.tag=indexPath.row`

Comment: The sorry state of iOS development...

Comment: one way is to use Protocols. Which will call the delegate implemented method from the CustomCell's -(IBAction)imageButtonAction;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add this code :

```
[cell.imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Declare and define this `-(IBAction)imageButtonAction;` function in that particular class where you are using this customized cell.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in your cellforrow at index path after you specify cell. It will call the method when you click on button in cell

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below line in cellforrowatindexpath: method

[cell.imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

and dont forget to make method for imageButtonAction